# Swagger is not showing any controllers or endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

[Swagger Api Docs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY6Tg.png)

I am working on adding / integrating swagger in my springboot project. I have tried different things but its not got fixed. All that is showing now is white page without any endpoints or controllers and just an empty page with swagger logo.

Swagger URL is : http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

My swagger configurations are given below:

```
package com.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.app.controller"})
public class StoreApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            SpringApplication.run(StoreApplication.class, args);

        }catch (Throwable throwable){
            System.out.println(throwable.toString());
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller code.

*My Controller*

```
package com.app.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class CustomersController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<?> getAllCustomers(){


        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<?> createCustomer(){


        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
    }

}
```

Here is the main class

*Main Class*

```
package com.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.app.controller"})
public class StoreApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            SpringApplication.run(StoreApplication.class, args);

        }catch (Throwable throwable){
            System.out.println(throwable.toString());
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my app config file

*AppConfig*

```
package com.app.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){

      //  registry.addRedirectViewController("/docApi/v2/api-docs","/v2/api-docs");
        registry.addViewController("/welcome").setViewName("Welcome");
    }


}
```

Comment: how did you configuration your swagger? provide more details. @Alee

Comment: Add some configuration, how your endpoints look like (what annotation have you added), how you generated that page

Comment: @Dolphin I have added the swagger configuration details.

Comment: That's not enough, you can check the url and followed by it step by step: https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api @Alee there is a minimal example: https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-boot-swagger-example

Comment: @Dolphin
I have updated the details now. Please check.

Comment: I have updated and provided all the details on my post . Please check. @Mateusz

Answer (score 0):

First, try to add swagger config like this:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {


    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.app"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

then add some annotation in your controller like this:

```
package com.app.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@Api
public class CustomersController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ApiOperation(value = "get all", tags = "customer")
    ResponseEntity<?> getAllCustomers(){


        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ApiOperation(value = "create", tags = "customer")
    ResponseEntity<?> createCustomer(){


        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
    }

}
```

hope this would fix your problem. Then try to access the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`, pay attention not the url `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`.

Comment: Problem remains same even after following this. @Dolphin

Comment: I take some time and make a minimal demo and tweak my answer, try to change the access url and try again. @AleeRaza or leave me an email I could send the demo to you.

Comment: Problem not solved yet. @Dolphin Share your email address.

Comment: my email address is: jiangtingqiang@gmail.com. you can send your minimal demo and I will try to solve your problem. @Alee Raza